# Execute standard output with function

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

I have a script which sets my prompt (included below). Rather than copying and saving it on each system that it uses, I want to download and run it with `$(curl <url>)`. However, when I run it from bash, I get this error: `-bash: function: command not found`. How do I fix this?

```
function parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}

function parse_pwd () {
  pwd | sed -e 's#/var/www/#%#' | sed -e 's#/home/myusername#~#'
}

function prompt () {
  echo "$BRANCH_COLOR\$(parse_git_branch)$USERNAME_COLOR`whoami`$PATH_COLOR\$(parse_pwd)$PROMPT_COLOR "
}

USERNAME_COLOR="\[\033[0;37m\]" #gray
BRANCH_COLOR="\[\033[0;33m\]" #yellow
PATH_COLOR="\[\033[1;32m\]" #green; bold
PROMPT_COLOR="\[\033[0m\]" #none (white)

PS1="$(prompt)"
```

Comment: Post the full script. (A script starts with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line.)

Comment: @Gilles: You do not **have** to use a shebang line for a script.

Comment: @JayBienvenu: Which line exactly gives you the error message?

Comment: @user1934428 You do if you want the script to be an executable program. If you don't then the script can only be executed by specifying an interpreter. Or you can invoke an executable program and let the caller decide — that usually results in execution by some sh-style shell, but not always the same and not necessarily bash. Case in point, without a shebang line, how do you ensure that bash is executing the script and not some other sh that doesn't have a `function` keyword?

Comment: @Gilles: This is what I meant (I see that I should have been more explicit in this case): Remove the execute rights, and call the script by specifying explicitly the interpreter. I should have said this. Note that I'm not against the shebang line - I'm using it often myself - but I can imagine cases where it is at least a valid option to not have one. That's why I objected agains your wording that *a script starts with a shebang line*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the `function` keyword - it is possible your Bash is ancient or some weird fork which doesn't support it. It's a redundant [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) anyway, so nothing is lost by removing it.

Comment: Has there ever been a bash version which did not accept this keyword? I don't remember one, and the [bash changes wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges) also doesn't mention its introduction at some later time.

Comment: I have no idea when it was introduced. There are some truly ancient/weirdly patched installations still around, so in these cases I always suspect weirdness if it works for me.

Comment: I don't understand that comment in this context.